# Programmatically "hide" a Test Advertisement

Tags: xcode, iad

is there any way I could simulate an iAd (Test Advertisement) being unloaded?
I want to find out if the rest of my app behaves as it's supposed to when switching ads or there are no available ads to show.

TIA! :)
/Lumpa

Comment: Show your iAd code, and I can show you how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes turn on airplane mode. You might need to reboot the device as iAd cashes the data..